# HTML Email : Transparent Layer of Text to the bottom of the image

Tags: html, css, html-table

I want a transparent text layer to the bottom of image.

[image: just like this image]

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td style="vertical-align:top; background:#ffffff;width:20%;display:inline-block;margin-left:20px;padding:0;text-align:center; background: #FFFFFF;">

      <img style=" padding-top:10px; outline: none;text-decoration: none;-ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic;" alt="" src="http://www.hubilo.com/eventApp/ws//images/speaker/profile/thumb/2712_1455301580.jpeg" border="0" height="110" width="110" >
      <!--  
      <p style=" width: 100%; text-align:center; font-size:10px;word-break: break-all; text-transform: uppercase; max-width: 110px; padding: 0px 5px; margin: 0 auto; background: #EE163A;">Mr. Mahesh Murthy</p>    
      <p style=" width: 100%; text-align:center; font-size:8px;word-break: break-all;  text-transform: uppercase; max-width: 110px; padding:0px 5px; padding-right: 5px; margin: 0 auto; background: #EE163A;"> 
        Co-founder at seefund 
      </p>-->
    </td>
  </table>
```

I don't know how to do without using `position` property.

PS: I am making HTML Emailer , so have to use `table` tag and **inside css** only. Can not use `div` , `position` property.

Thank You.

Comment: If you know how high that text element will be, then you could try and move it up using a negative margin-top.

Answer (score 0):

```
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td style="vertical-align:top; background:#ffffff;width:20%;display:inline-block;margin-left:20px;padding:0;text-align:center; background: #FFFFFF;">
      <div style="width: 110px; height: 110px;"> 
          <img style=" padding-top:10px; outline: none;text-decoration: none;-ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic;" alt="" src="http://www.hubilo.com/eventApp/ws//images/speaker/profile/thumb/2712_1455301580.jpeg" border="0" height="110" width="110">
          <p style="width: 100%;text-align:center;font-size:10px;word-break: break-all;/* text-transform: uppercase; */max-width: 110px;padding: 0px 5px;margin: 0 auto;background: rgba(45, 41, 42, 0.5);color: white;position: relative;bottom: 25px;">Mr. Mahesh Murthy</p>
          <p style="width: 100%;text-align:center;font-size:8px;word-break: break-all;/* text-transform: uppercase; */max-width: 110px;padding:0px 5px;padding-right: 5px;margin: 0 auto;position: relative;bottom: 25px;background: rgba(45, 41, 42, 0.5);color: white;"> Co-founder at seefund </p>
        </div></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: without using position , is it possible? As some email clients won't render **position** property.

Answer (score 0):

Something like that, but is that really not possible to use the `position` ? Because you won't be able to move it to the top. You might need to add a `z-index` property, requied `position` too.

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td style="vertical-align:top;width:20%;display:inline-block;margin-left:20px;padding:0;text-align:center; background: #FFFFFF;"><img style=" padding-top:10px; outline: none;text-decoration: none;-ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic;" alt="" src="http://www.hubilo.com/eventApp/ws//images/speaker/profile/thumb/2712_1455301580.jpeg" border="0" height="110" width="110" >
      <p style=" width:100px; text-align:center; font-size:10px;word-break: break-all; text-transform: uppercase; max-width: 110px; padding: 0px 5px; margin: 0 auto; background: #EE163A;  background:rgba(255,200,255,0.5); position:relative; top:-25px;">Mr. Mahesh Murthy</p>
       
      <!--   <p style=" width: 100%; text-align:center; font-size:8px;word-break: break-all;  text-transform: uppercase; max-width: 110px; padding:0px 5px; padding-right: 5px; margin: 0 auto; background:rgba(150,150,150,0.5); position:relative; top:-10px;"> Co-founder at seefund </p>--></td>
</table>
```

Comment: without using position , is it possible? As some email clients won't render **position** property.